# 404 error on github. The site configured at this address does not contain the requested file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: 404 error]

Hello all. I am getting the 404 error i have put in the picture. When I try to commit a react.js project it gives me this error. Not sure how to correct it. I've done a couple things. Can someone help me with it?[image: reporsitory]

[image: package.jason]

Comment: follow this guide on [how to create Github page site](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site)